# How to get rgb pixel value from R ,G,B value in java for a BufferedImage

Tags: java, image-processing

I can get the r,g,b values using the following functions.

```
int rgb=bImg.getRGB(i, j);
int r=(rgb>>16) & 0xff; 
int g=(rgb>>8) & 0xff;
int b=(rgb) & 0xff;
```

Now I do some operations in on those values and want to set the rgb values using the following function

```
bImg.setRgb(int x,int y,int rgb)
```

But i do not know how to calculate rgb from R,G,B values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int rgb = (r<<16) + (g<<8) + b;
```

Or

```
int rgb = (r<<16)  | (g<<8)  | b;
```

will do the inverse operation and store `r` , `g` and `b` into a single integer as you have decoded.