# How to create an array of pixel values?

Tags: java, arrays, image, rgb, pixel

I am trying to create a double-scripted array that has all the RGB values of an image in java. Afterwards, I want to see whether the pixel is black or white. However, the following code gives me an ArrayIndexOutofBounds Error and I'm not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
int[][] imageArr = new int[image.getTileHeight()+1][image.getTileWidth()+1];
    for (int a=0; a<image.getTileHeight(); a++)
    {
        for (int b=0; b<image.getTileWidth(); b++)
        {
            imageArr[a][b] = image.getRGB(a,b);               
        }
    }
```

---

Stack Trace of error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!
    at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.getDataElements(ByteInterleavedRaster.java:318)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(BufferedImage.java:888)
    at image2.main(image2.java:34)
```

Comment: The code looks ok to me. Is it possible that the `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsError` came from `image.getRGB()`?

Comment: I'm not sure...the error states: "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds! (in sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster)

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace? Does it include `getRGB()`? Learning to read a stack trace is an essential Java skill.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what that means. I'm a beginner.

Comment: After the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` there should be a list of method names, file names and line numbers. Each line should start with the word "at". Copy and paste that into your question.

Comment: is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes. The stack trace shows that the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` came from `java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB()`.

Comment: How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39605/discussion-between-user1755178-and-pburka)

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880083/get-rgb-of-a-bufferedimage) may be of help to you

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to get it for the complete image then you need to use `getHeight` and `getWidth` not `getTileHeight` and `getTileWidth` in your loops and array initialisation.

These are causing the `getRBG` to throw the `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` as it trying to get the image of the `Raster` data embedding within your `BufferedImage`