# identify Blank Image Using Java

Tags: java, image

Hi How can we identify Blank Image(White Image),

```
BufferReaderImage im = ImageIO.read("samplePath");
```

the image iam passing is empty with some height and width, i want to identify it

[image]

Comment: Can you give us some more details on what you've tried, i.e. some research?

Comment: What do you mean by “blank”? White? Transparent?

Comment: @gurghet i had uploaded the image, we are unable to see the image there..i want to identify it and handle it.

Comment: @ricky3350 while reading the image with ImageIO.read(); am getting this i want to handle the thing and replace with another.. i didnt get idea how to know that is blank image.

Comment: ...no , don't put a blank image here. !!!

Answer (score 0):

This link should help you get started:

[Get RGB values of a BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880083/get-rgb-of-a-bufferedimage)

In particular, this is the relevant part:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(
     new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png"));

int w = image.getWidth();
int h = image.getHeight();

int[] dataBuffInt = image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, null, 0, w); 

Color c = new Color(dataBuffInt[100]);

System.out.println(c.getRed());   // = (dataBuffInt[100] >> 16) & 0xFF
System.out.println(c.getGreen()); // = (dataBuffInt[100] >> 8)  & 0xFF
System.out.println(c.getBlue());  // = (dataBuffInt[100] >> 0)  & 0xFF
System.out.println(c.getAlpha()); // = (dataBuffInt[100] >> 24) & 0xFF
```

Then go through all the entries and make sure there are some different values.

Comment: It didnt worked... jarodeells, Its giving same value for blank image and black& white images like 255,255,255,255