# How to get an image matriz in a fast way? JAVA

Tags: java, image, image-processing, matrix, rgb

I'm trying to get an image matriz (pixels configuration) in a fast way... In JAVA

I can get the matriz but depend the resolution of the pic, it takes a lot of time, so if somebody knows how to get it in a fast way, please tell me.

```
        int a;
        int r ; 
        int g ; 
        int b ;

            for(int y = 0; y < bufImage2.getHeight(); y++) {
                for(int x = 0 ; x < bufImage2.getWidth(); x++){
                    color = new Color(bufImage2.getRGB(x, y));
                    a = color.getAlpha();
                    r = color.getRed(); 
                    g = color.getGreen(); 
                    b = color.getBlue(); 
                    System.out.print(r+"."+g+"."+b+":");
                    }
```

That's the "for" that I use to get the RGB values.

If there are libraries or something to do it more fast tell me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a similar question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880083/get-rgb-of-a-bufferedimage), here is what i have found for you, BufferedImage has its own getRGB function, it just has to be processed to get the values at any point (pixX, pixY)

```
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();

        int[] dataBuffInt = image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, null, 0, w); 

        int pixX = 25;
        int pixY = 50;

        Color c = new Color(dataBuffInt[pixX+pixY*w]);

        System.out.println(c.getRed());   // = (dataBuffInt[100] >> 16) & 0xFF
        System.out.println(c.getGreen()); // = (dataBuffInt[100] >> 8)  & 0xFF
        System.out.println(c.getBlue());  // = (dataBuffInt[100] >> 0)  & 0xFF
        System.out.println(c.getAlpha()); // = (dataBuffInt[100] >> 24) & 0xFF
```

Comment: But with that code I scan all the image ? Because I need all the values of all the pixels. 

@Kore

Comment: @DennerPortuguez yes, you define the size of the picture you want to read as:
int[] dataBuffInt = image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, null, 0, w);
0 and 0 being start X and Y and w, h being end X and Y